# Server-side implementation of image downloading in Django web app (images served from a remote location)

Tags: django

I'm trying to do a server side implementation of a download button for static assets (served via AWS S3) in a Django web app.

**What I've tried:**

I first tried the `download` attribute with `a` tags. But it doesn't cover Firefox in my experience (i.e. instead of the asset being downloaded, a new browser tab opens and the asset renders in that window).

I tried a server-side solution once the aforementioned failed. Specifically, in an html template, I've got:

```
<form method="GET" action="{% url 'download_image' %}" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="img_url" value="{{ img_url }}">
    <button>Download</button>
</form>
```

And in a view, I'm trying:

```
def download_image(request):
    """
    Download the image
    """
    image_url = request.GET.get("img_url",None)
    # image_url value is //s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/my-app/ebc4596f-d7db-340f-b7d6-4952c949f011.jpg
    if image_url:
        with open('https:'+image_url, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="image/jpg")
            response["Content-Disposition"] = 'attachment; filename="content.jpg"'
            return response
```

This results in an `IOError`:

> No such file or directory:
>   u'https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/my-app/ebc4596f-d7db-340f-b7d6-4952c949f011.jpg'

I feel I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. Can an expert guide me via an illustrative example? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open()` opens a local file in your file system.
To get remote files I prefer `requests`

```
import requests


image_response = requests.get(image_url)
if image_response.status_code != requests.status_codes.codes.ok:
    # error handling

response = HttpResponse(image_response.content, content_type=image_response.headers['Content-Type'])
...
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it. I'll get back to you after trying it out in a bit.